# Acer e5-721 touchpad

Tags: touchpad, acer

Touchpad l and screen dimmer doesn't work on new Ubuntu 14.04 install.  Fn f7 doesn't do anything.  And dimmer doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing proper drivers for Touchpad and hotkeys. You should consider contacting the laptop vendor's website for help on this!